# How to get lat and long of center google map iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I’m building an iOS app using storyboards.I integrated google map in my app and getting location address on tapping.

I want to implement a pin at map centre on scrolling map pin will move and give the location address same as in Uber or Ola Cabs app.

Could some one help me how i can implement this,i found one tutorial(http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) but it is in swift but i have to implement in objective c.

here is my code:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

    // coordinate contains your coordinate :)

    NSLog(@"did tap at coordinate: (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

         NSString *address=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&key=AIzaSjhsdfg67tahdsg8981k8_5aJoZps",coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:address];

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if ((unsigned long)data.length > 3) {

        // NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *file=@"/Data.json";

        [data writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

        NSArray *ys_avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        NSLog(@"array=%@",ys_avatars);

            NSLog(@"status====%@",[ys_avatars valueForKey:@"status"]);

             if([[ys_avatars valueForKey:@"status"]  isEqual: @"OK"]){

        NSArray *results=[ys_avatars valueForKey:@"results"];

            NSLog(@"formatted_address====%@",[results valueForKey:@"formatted_address"] );

            NSArray *address=[results valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];

            NSLog(@"add=%@",address[0]);

               _myAddress.text=address[0];

        }

  }

}
```

Comment: If I understand it right, you always to want to get the lat and long of the centre of the map? That's how UBER works, if that's the case I don't think you need to implement didTapAtCoordinate instead you should be using - mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:

Comment: @Vig ThanksYeaaa you are absolutely right could you give me an code example how i can implement this – 
could you please tell me how i can lat and long at the centre of camera position,am i right this is what we need to implement this –

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment so to respond to your question, you can get lat and long of the centre of the map this way:

```
    - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
       double latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude;
       double longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude;

       CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);


        marker.position = center;

 }
```